# How do I record the details of stored procedure calls?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my current project, we are running into issues that could be very easily debugged (in our dev environment) by knowing the calls being made, alongside their respective parameters. In an effort to make that happen, I've established a table which stores the PROC name, as well as some arbitrary JSON blob containing all the parameters with which it was called. I'm also storing call time, but that's irrelevant.

Following is the only way I've found to populate this table:

```
    DECLARE @prmJson NVARCHAR(MAX) = (  SELECT * FROM (VALUES       
            ('@userId'              ,   @userId                )
        ,   ('@baiCodeMerchantId'   ,   @baiCodeMerchantId     )
        ,   ('@baiCodeMerchantType' ,   @baiCodeMerchantType   )
        ,   ('@appliedAccountId'    ,   @appliedAccountId      )
        ,   ('@unappliedAccountId'  ,   @unappliedAccountId    )) AS P(Name, Value) FOR JSON AUTO);
    INSERT INTO History.SprocCallRecords ([SprocName], [ParametersJson])
    VALUES (QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)), @prmJson);
```

My issue is, this is a lot of code to add to *every single procedure*. I'd much rather be able to reflect on the in-scope values, or be able to call some C#-like nameof() method. While I'm obviously projecting other languages onto tSQL, I would very much like to simplify this boilerplate before I integrate it anywhere.

Mostly, I'm looking for suggestions, but there isn't much I was able to find on Google RE: precisely this.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Just use SQL Profiler?? Or Auditing/Extended Events. You don't need to invent a new solution. Caveat: Profiler and Auditing capture loads of stuff so performance may suffer while running. Extended Events would be of similar impact to your solution though

Comment: I'm not sure they can capture parameters, though. I did look at that option, but it seemed to lack what I actually needed, which is the parameters.

Comment: No all 3 can certainly capture parameters... auditing wouldn't be very useful if it couldn't capture everything

Comment: Fair enough! I'll go look into it again. Thanks!

Comment: https://jackworthen.com/2018/07/23/capturing-the-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-call-using-sql-server-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

You can call the stored procedures dynamically, so you will be able to save each call to some log table.

Example:

```
    DECLARE 
    @param1 nvarchar(50),
    @param2 nvarchar(50),
    @param3 nvarchar(50)

SET @param1 = 'value of param 1'
SET @param2 = 'value of param 2'
SET @param3 = 'value of param 3'

DECLARE @sp_text nvarchar(2000)
SET @sp_text = 'exec some_sp ''' + @param1 + ''', ''' + @param2 + ''', ''' + @param3 + ''''

INSERT INTO Executions_Log_Table(Execution_DT, SP_Call) SELECT GetDate(), @sp_text
EXEC(@sp_text)
```

Hope to help you